# What does "more than killing me to kill me" means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), Dr Strange uses his corpse in another universe to perform [Dreamwalking](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Dreamwalking).
During this process, he collects the souls around him, which become his multiple hands,
and meets Scarlet Witch:

> Dr Strange: This time, it's gonna take **more than killing me to kill me**.

What does "more than killing me to kill me" means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is deliberately weird; that's appropriate to a magical character called "Dr Strange".

Suppose the bad-guy had tried to kill superman by stabbing them. But because superman can't be killed by knives he might say

> It will take more than stabbing me, to kill me.

It means that to kill superman the bad guy would need to do something more extreme than stabbing (such a shooting with kryptonite bullets)

But in the case of Dr Strange. The bad guy killed Dr Strange, but he came back to life (by magic) Dr Strange can't be killed by being killed.

Hence "It will take more than killing me, to kill me"

Killing Dr Strange isn't enough, you also have to take away his magic powers, otherwise he could come back to life.